# How long are steam purchases valid?

Tags: steam

Having always purchased hard copies of games I am a bit apprehensive about going all digital.My main concern once I have a steam game in my library is there a download limit/number of installation on the game.Is it safe to say that I can dump physical copies for good?

Answer (score 8):

The games you buy are yours forever (or rather a very long time) and can be installed on as many computers as you want (unless the game has a limit on its own, but the same limitation would likely be on the physical edition too).

Dumping physical copies is a decision you must make, but as I stated below, Steam has been around for 13 years already, and they are likely to be around for a very long time. I don't like physical copies as buying, storing, moving and organizing them is hard yet losing them is pretty easy.

Steam is generating billions of dollars every year and is unlikely to go bankrupt, and even if it did, most developers would provide a way to move your games to another platform, like most developers did when Desura went bankrupt.

Comment: Only Restriction: Some games might force you the Steam Client.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 To be fair, even hard copies will occasionally require the Steam client. IIRC, when I got my hard copy of Skyrim, it asked me for my Steam account details so it could download all the updates from there.

Comment: One other thing worth mentioning: It's _way_ easier to install Steam games when you rebuild your computer. The only thing you need to remember to download is Steam itself, and then you can install the games you want, when you want to play them (or a bit before), rather than having to hunt for the CD/DVD.

Comment: To be added, that IF you break Steam rules, your account can be banned, so you can lose access. However for normal people who don't cheat, etc, this is not a real problem. But if you want to do nasty things, then Steam can get rid of you. :)

Comment: @AntoineHejlík no. You only get VAC banned if you cheat. You do get community (unable to add friends etc) or trade banned if you try to scam people though. Losing access to all your games is pretty hard, and steam rarely bans people completely (they only ban you completely for 6 months if you buy something and contact your bank and chargeback).